# Printing number of items from a data file

Tags: python-2.7

I have only just started learning to program with school and one of the assignments we had to do was to open a data file and print the number of items within it. I have tried using row_count function but I can't seem to get either to work!! Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

row_count = sum(5 for row in input_file)

print row_count

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/files/reading-and-writing-files-in-python). Also, what do you mean by number of items? Do you mean number of lines?

Comment: Thanks for the link, and yes, the number of lines. Many Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want `readlines()` and `len()`:

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    print(len(f.readlines()))
```